# I would say: "You are another teacher", but she is a woman and I am a man

Tags: meaning-in-context, gender

Ich möchte sagen: "You are another teacher,...".

Die Spiegelübersetzung wäre: "Du bist ein anderer Lehrer". Das Problem ist, daß sie eine "Sie" ist, also sollte sie als "Lehrerin" bezeichnet werden.  Nach dem, was ich weiß, kann das beleidigend sein.

Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre: "Du bist eine andere Lehrerin". Aber damit würde ich mich als weiblich definieren, was wahrscheinlich mißverständlich klingen würde.

Welche Variante ist besser?  Wie sollte ich es sagen?

Comment: Potential für Verstimmungen würde ich sogar eher in "ein anderer" sehen. Ist mit "You are another teacher" vielleicht eher etwas wie "Du bist ein weiterer Lehrer" oder "Du bist ebenfalls Lehrer" gemeint? "Ein anderer Lehrer" wäre eher etwas wie "a different teacher" oder "a different kind of teacher". Da könnte man meiner Meinung nach durchaus etwas Abschätziges hineinlesen (z. B. "Du bist halt eine andere Art Lehrer, Du hast nicht die nötige Kompetenz"). Die Frage des grammatikalischen Geschlechts kommt dann noch dazu.

Comment: "Du bist doch auch Mitglied der Lehrkörpers."  ;-)

Comment: "Wir sind LehrerInnen" ?

Comment: In welchem Zusammenhang denn; was willst Du ausdrücken? "Du bist doch auch Lehrer"? Was würdest Du zu einem Mann sagen? "Anderer Lehrer" kann heißen "Mathe, nicht Deutsch", "Antroposophisch, nicht staatlich", irgendwie auf vielfältige Weise individuell unterschiedlich und wohl manches mehr.

Comment: Oder ist gemeint "noch ein Lehrer"?

Comment: Oje, warum so kompliziert? Nimm die Schweizer Verniedlichung und sag einfach "Du bisch (im Fall) 's and're Lehrerli". Schön neutral 

Comment: Die Frage ist zunächst einmal, was der Satz überhaupt heißen soll. Soll er heißen: "Du bist eine Lehrkraft von anderer Art als ich. Du unterrichtest anders." Oder soll es heißen: "Auch du bist eine Lehrkraft." - Die richtige Ausformung deines Satzes wäre für beide Fälle anders.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Der folgende Satz wird von Sprechern unterschiedlich bewertet (Stichwort: *generisches Maskulinum*). Als beleidigend kann er aber meines Erachtens nicht aufgefaßt werden.*

> *(an eine weibliche Person gerichtet)* Du bist ein anderer Lehrer.

Um ihn dennoch zu vermeiden, schlage ich vor:

> Du bist eine andere Lehrkraft.

Hier steht eine Femininum sowohl für Männer als auch für Frauen (woran sich niemand stört).

<sub>* Die Diskussion um das generische Maskulinum – die ich soweit als möglich **nicht** hier hineinziehen möchte, da das Thema erfahrungsgemäß zu Aufregung führt – drehte sich immer darum, welche gesellschaftlichen Folgen es haben mag, wenn maskuline Nomen mal Männer, mal Gruppen von Männern und Frauen bezeichnen. Es ging dagegen nie darum, daß ein einzelnes Individuum durch einen Satz der Form *Maria, du bist doch Lehrer, hilf mir mal!* beleidigt würde.</sub>

Comment: Ich glaube Dir :-)

Comment: `Maria, du bist doch Lehrer, hilf mir mal!` Ich wäre beleidigt, weil das _bitte_ fehlt ;)

Comment: Worth noting is that Lehrkraft sounds kinda formal imo.
Still a nice solution to just avoid the whole thing

Comment: In der Fußnote fehlt der nicht unwichtige Fall, dass das Geschlecht unbekannt ist und auch keine Rolle spielt. "Wenn ein Schüler glaubt, 10 + 2 sei 102, dann hat wohl der Lehrer versagt."

Comment: da kann nur der Lehrer versagt haben. (wobei: Lehrer gibt es bei uns kaum mehr, wenn dann alles nur noch Lehrerinnen sind, wäre diese Problem ein für allemal und endültig gelöst! apropos Geschlecht: im Lehrplan 21 steht jetzt überall "SuS", ich hab's nicht gezählt wie oft. Aber was bedeutet der Schwachsinn? "*Schülerinnen und Schüler*" (oder umgekehrt?). Damit die Lehrerinnen und Lehrer (oder umgekehrt?)  ja immer schön daran denken, dass mit Schülerinnen auch die Schüler mitgemeint sind. (oder umgekehrt ...)

Comment: Die Frage dreht sich aber darum, ob man das generische Maskulinum hier vermeiden soll. Inwiefern für ein generisches Femininum anderes gelten soll (die Lehrkraft) erschließt sich mir nicht.

Answer (score 14):

Es ist nicht immer einfach, in solchen Sachen das richtige Geschlecht zu wählen. Ich empfehle, den Satz anders zu bauen.

If you want to say that she prefers a different teaching method:

> Du bist eine andere Art (von) Lehrer.

Hier bezieht sich das Geschlecht auf "Art", und das ist ok.

If you want to say that she's a teacher, same as you:

> Du unterrichtest auch.
>   Wir sind beide Lehrer.

Die meisten Berufe lassen sich auf ein Verb zurückführen. "Du lehrst auch" wäre hier dem Ursprung näher, wird so aber kaum noch verwendet. In der Schule wird unterrichtet.

Comment: +1 für "Wir sind beide Lehrer"

Answer (score 5):

If you leave off the article altogether, it becomes a profession used in a manner similar to an adjective.  "Sie sind ja auch Lehrer" is ungendered as opposed to "Sie sind ja auch ein Lehrer" and does not imply misgendering the addressed person.  This difference is interesting since "Sie sind ja auch Lehrerin" is perfectly feasible and *does* imply gender, usually in the "you as well know about problems specific to female teachers" sense.  Of course, depending on whether one addresses a person with a vested interest of changing the language's gender perception, even "Sie sind ja auch Lehrer" could be cause of corrective measures since it clearly is asymmetric in use with "Sie sind ja auch Lehrerin".

But on the straightforward level of current-day language, "Sie sind ja auch Lehrer" is much much less a case for taking misgenderisation offense than "Sie sind ja auch ein Lehrer" would be.

Answer (score 1):

Aus der Frage geht nicht ganz klar hervor, was der genaue Kontext ist und ich denke je nach Kontext gibt es verschiedene Lösungen, da "another" nämlich zwei Bedeutungen haben: "different" (eine Menge abgrenzend) oder "one more" (eine Menge erweiternd).

**Abgrenzung**

Möchte man jemanden abgrenzen (zum Beispiel, da der Gesprächspartner eine andere Lehrstrategie verfolgt), dann passt die vorgeschlagene Übersetzung: "Du bist ein anderer Lehrer". Dies sollte auch im allgemeinen nicht missverstanden und/oder beleidigend verstanden werden, selbst wenn der Gesprächspartner eine Lehrerin ist (siehe [David Vogts Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50478/33430)). Dennoch lässt sich auch hier ohne Probleme sagen: "Du bist eine andere Lehrerin", ohne dass man (meiner Meinung nach) automatisch sich als Frau zu erkennen gibt. Möchte man das ganze Mann/Frau Dilemma vermeiden, kann man immer noch Neutralformen (z.B. Lehrkraft) verwenden.

**Erweiterung**

Geht es aber nicht darum den Gesprächspartner von sich oder jemandem anderen abzugrenzen, sollte auch eine andere Übersetzung gewählt werden. Ich würde vorschlagen: "Du bist auch Lehrer(in)" zu verwenden. Hier gilt (meiner Meinung nach) das gleiche Prinzip, das beide Formen (Lehrer oder Lehrerin) keineswegs automatisch implizieren, dass beide Gesprächspartner das gleiche Geschlecht haben. Und natürlich lässt sich auch in dieser Konstruktion eine Neutralform verwenden ("Du bist auch Lehrkraft").

Comment: Ich bin gar nicht so sicher, ob `another` wirklich auch mal `different` bedeuten kann (ohne einen deutlichen Schwerpunkt auf `one more` zu haben, und das Anderssein ist ja inhärent bei einem weiteren Individuum).  Ich kenne es eigentlich nur mit der Bedeutung `one more` und die vermeintliche Bedeutung `different` als _False Friend_, weil das `ein anderer` im Deutschen die Bedeutung das `different` durchaus enthält.  Test:  Gibt es Fälle, wo jemand etwas _ersetzen_ will (also nicht ergänzen), z. B. "we need another light bulb" nach einem Defekt?  Ich denke das ist unüblich.

Comment: "Der Lehrer" ist grammatisch männlich, ohne es inhaltlich zu sein, genauso wie "die Lehrkraft" weiblich ist, ohne es inhaltlich zu sein. Es ist inkonsistent und bemerkenswert, wie selbstverständlich dieses Auseinanderfallen von Geschlecht des Wortes und Geschlecht des Bezeichneten bei "die Lehrkraft" übersehen wird, für "der Lehrer" aber inzwischen geschluckt wird.

Comment: @Alfe Hier sind zwei Links, die meine Interpretation ein bisschen stützen: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/another und https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another. Ich gebe zu, dass "different" nicht komplett synonym mit "another" ist, mir fällt nur kein besseres Wort ein.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist doch völlig neben dem Punkt für die Frage und meine Antwort. In direkten Gesprächen (und insbesondere in der Situation der Fragestellung) sind die Geschlechter bekannt. peterh möchte seiner Gesprächspartnerin entgegenkommen und sie als Lehrerin bezeichnen, befürchtet aber sich damit ebenfalls als weiblich zu titulieren. Das hat nichts mit grammatikalischer Herkunft, gendergerechter Sprache, möglicher Diskriminierung durch das generische Maskulinum oder Inkonsistenz zu tun. Ich habe die Neutralform nur deshalb angeführt, da es peterh als Alternative interessieren könnte.

Comment: @QueensKnight: "Die Lehrkraft" ist eben in keiner Weise neutraler als "der Lehrer", das gilt es zu begreifen. Und weil "der Lehrer" eben eine Berufs-, keine Geschlechtsbezeichnung ist, ist es kein Entgegenkommen - allenfalls ein Entegegenkommen in den Irrtum - "du bist ein anderer Lehrer" als Beleidigung aufzufassen. Eine Frau als Lehrer zu bezeichnen ist eben oft richtig, aber einen Mann als Lehrerin ist immer falsch.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich persönlich sehe jetzt zwar nicht in wie weit das meine Antwort betrifft (es sei denn Sie stört meine Formulierung der "Neutralform", in dem Fall wären Sie bitte so freundlich mir einen Alternativvorschlag für diese Formulierung anzubieten?). An keiner Stelle fordere dass sich jemand wegen meiner vorgestellten Sätze beleidigt fühlen sollte. Fakt ist aber, dass dies passieren kann und daher meine "Neutralform" als dritter Vorschlag der mögliche Missverständnisse umgehen sollte.

Comment: @QueensKnight: Umgekehrt, erklär doch mal, was an Deiner Form neutral ist.

Comment: Es gibt Menschen, die "Lehrerin" als weibliche Berufsbezeichnung ansehen. Es gibt Menschen, die aufgrund dieser (abgeleiteten) Bezeichnung und einer historischen Bevorteilungen von Männern in der Berufswelt, die männliche Berufsbezeichnung als generische ablehnen. Soweit die Fakten (über die Korrektheit der Annahmen und Ablehnung lässt sich streiten). Lehrkraft ist "neutral", da es keine abgeleitete Version davon gibt (neutral wie Basis), keine historische Belastung vorliegt (neutral im Sinne von Bias) und er von entsprechenden Interessengruppen akzeptiert wird (neutral wie sozial akzeptabel).

Comment: Was denn jetzt, sind es Fakten oder lässt s. drüber streiten? Es gibt keine Sonderstellung von Berufen in der Sprache. Das gleiche, generische Muster findest Du bei Hobbys (Kegler, Fußballer), bei Nationalitäten (Briten, Amis), bei delinquentem Verhalten (Mörder, Dieb). Die historische Bevorteilung von Männern - durch wen? - ist ebenfalls nur aus der Luft gegriffen. Lehrkraft ist ein weiblicher Begriff, kein neutraler, wie Lehrer ein männlicher Begriff ist. Beide Begriffe verraten nichts über das Geschlecht des Lehrers. Der Begriff Lehrer ist auch nicht belastet. Lehrkraftin gibt's nicht, ja.

Answer (score 1):

> Wir sind unterschiedliche Lehrer

Answer (score 0):

Die Version mit dem Genderstern wäre:

> Du bist ein*e andere*r Lehrer*in

Mündlich würde man die Position des Sterns ausdrücken, indem man eine an Stelle des Sterns eine kurze Lücke lässt.

Comment: Nur macht das niemand, ohne eine Gewisse soziale Distanz zu seinem Gegenüber aufzubauen.  Es ist einfach (noch?) unüblich, mit Lücken zu sprechen, und auch dem menschlichen Sprachapparat nicht geläufig.

Comment: @Alfe das kommt ganz auf das soziale Umfeld an. Ich habe durch aus einige Freund_innen, die ganz selbstverständlich mit Lücke sprechen.

Comment: Hier ist das Gegenüber (also der Kontext) aber gegeben: eine Lehrerin.  Ich habe gerade Schwierigkeiten, mir vorzustellen, dass eine Lehrerin diese Sprechweise normal findet.  Ich wollte auch nur darauf hinweisen, dass die (noch?) nicht allgemeine Akzeptanz dieser Lösung durchaus erwähnenswert ist.

Comment: Im universitären Kontext begegne ich dieser Sprechweise durchaus häufiger. Welches Geschlecht das Gegenüber hat, ist hier gerade egal, da  mit _Lehrer*in_ eben gerade gesagt wird, dass die Person eine Lehrperson ist, und über das Geschlecht keine Aussage gemacht wird.

Answer (score 0):

Die meisten Antworten hier gehen leider stark in die Irre.

> You are another teacher

heißt im typischen Fall der korrekten Anwendung des Englischen ja nicht

> **[Falsch!]**
>
> Du bist eine Lehrkraft von anderer Art.
>
> Du unterrichtest anders.

(Das wäre eher: *You are a different teacher.*)

Es heißt vielmehr etwas wie:

> **[Richtig!]**
>
> Auch du bist ein Lehrer / eine Lehrerin / Lehrkraft / Lehrperson
>
> Du bist noch<sup>1</sup> ein Lehrer / eine Lehrerin / Lehrkraft / Lehrperson
>
> Du bist ein weiterer Lehrer / eine weitere Lehrerin / Lehrkraft / Lehrperson

Merke wohl: Das Wort *Lehrperson* hat sich in den letzten Jahren, ausgehend von Österreich, auch im bundesdeutschen Sprachraum etabliert, jedenfalls unter Lehrpersonen, v.a. unter solchen, die zu ihrem Fachgebiet, der Pädagogik oder Andragogik, publizieren. Der Grund ist genau, der Genderdebatte, Gendersternchendebatte und Binnen-i-Debatte aus dem Weg zu gehen.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Noch* hier im Sinne von: *weiterer* (Mengenangabe), nicht etwas *bis jetzt* (Zeitangabe)

Answer (score -1):

*Leider erschließt sich der Kontext nicht, daher muss ich raten.*

Anstatt subjektivem Ausdruck wäre eine Verbalisierung des Objektes "Lehrer" möglich:

> Du lehrst anders

Oder rein objektiv:

> Dein Unterricht ist anders

---

Falls es tatsächlich um die Person geht, wäre ein Wort mit generischem Gender (davon sind Berufsbezeichnungen und andere Titel eben weitgehend ausgeschlossen) möglich, etwa

> Du bist ein ganz anderer Mensch, eine ganz andere Person.

oder das speziell dafür geeignete Pronomen **jemand**

> Du bist jemand ganz anderes

wobei aber einige der Tendenz folgen würden, Worten die *man* enthalten als ungerecht zu empfinden.

Dabei wirkt "ganz" wie adverbial "gänzlich" als Hervorhebung der Individualität, bzw. als Ausschluss der Zusammengehörigkeit (denn dass der Gegenüber nicht der Redner selbst ist, ist eigentlich offensichtlich, doch wegen Familiarität können die Grenzen der Selbstidentifikation fließend sein).

---

Wenn es um die Art Lehrer, nicht die Person Lehrer gehen sollte, wäre dieses oder ähnliches das passende Wort

> Du bist eine andere Art, ein anderer Typ Lehrer

Vorsicht! Typ ist homonym mit verkürztem "Typus" (type), hat aber auch eine andere, negativ besetzte Bedeutung und steht oft für seltsame oder unangenehme Männer.

---

Ein Kontext für die Phrase ist schwer zu erahnen. Ich denke, es sei ein eher unüblicher Ausdruck (nicht zuletzt wegen der in Frage gestellten Schwierigkeit).

Falls es bspw. darum ginge, die Aussage eines Kindes zu übersetzen, wäre für besonders junge Kinder sogar generisches Feminin denkbar, *du bist eine ganz andere Lehrerin* (Das hieße in der Regel aber eher förmlich *Sie sind*). Auch einige wenige Autoren benutzen inzwischen prinzipiell das generische Feminin (habe ich selbst aber noch nie gesehen).

Die oben erwähnte *Lehrkraft* (bei @David Vogt) wäre unpassend in allen weniger als förmlichen Situationen, insbesondere aus dem Mund eines Kindes. Oder eben wenn geduzt wird ("Du" statt "Sie"). Behelfsweise ist es korrekt. Ein Fremdsprachler, der zu förmlich spricht, wird zwar damit auffallen, aber kaum negativ. Ein anderes so spezifisches neutrales Wort fällt mir aber auch nicht ein.

---

**Was ist das genaue Problem? Eine generelle Antwort ohne Modifikationen der Phrase ist, wie du schon richtig sagst, nicht möglich.** Generisches Maskulin von Damen verwendet, bemerkte ich persönlich überhaupt erst vor kurzer Zeit daher möchte ich es nicht direkt bewerten. Ich pflege noch, es zu vermeiden. Selbst wenn nicht maskulinistisch, ist es zumindest verdinglichend (objectifying), as "vor kurzer Zeit" [f.] > "vor Kurzem" [m.] (Or what else is that all about?).